# Programmable ftp server

Tags: authentication, ftp, ftp-server

We have a need to set up a ftp server. Many clients will upload files regularly. Each client will use a different ftp account. We will be called by an external system to provision a new client - we can either take username/password from the external aystem or generate them and pass them back. We will probably want to create a directory per client for them to upload files.

When a client uploads a file, we want to be notified, process the file, and pass it on to another external system (then rename or otherwise identify the file as processed)

So I am after suggestions for a ftp server that can have accounts added programmatically. Ideally, it would also handle the directories and new-upload notifications, but we can do these in other ways.

This would be on Red Hat Linux (ideally), or Solaris is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Google says RedHat 9 Comes with vsftpd installed.

https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. It's not immediately obvious how to add users programmatically (there's the virtual users example, but I'm note sure if accounts can be added dynamically, or if virtual users can have different home directories)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible.  If not, it is open source.

Comment: Sure, everything's possible by coding it ourselves. I was hoping there's be something already available though.